# REST API integration to 3rd party

Tags: node.js, rest, express

I'm trying to create REST API. My API should return a list of users taken from a 3rd party (after some manipulations) and return it.

Here is my code:

```
function getUsersFrom3rdParty(options) {
    https.get(options, (resp) => {

    let data ='';
    // A chunk of data has been received.
    resp.on('data', (chunk) => {
        data += chunk;
    });

    // The whole response has been received. Print out the result.
    resp.on('end', () => {
        console.log(JSON.parse(data));
    });

}).on("error", (err) => {
    console.log("Error: " + err.message);
});

}

  exports.getUsers = (req, res, next) => {

   var data = getUsersFrom3rdParty();
 //do the manilupations and return to the api
};
```

I don't get the data in `getUsers` function.

Comment: 1. You're not actually calling the function; and 2. even if you did, the function doesn't deal with the asynchronous nature of the operation correctly.

Comment: Thanks!
How should I fix issue 2?

Comment: Read e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/3001761

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using something like `axios` - [npmjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) - for making asynchronous calls to a 3rd party API:

```js
const axios = require('axios')

function getUsersFrom3rdParty(options) {
  const processResponse = (response) => {
    const processedResponse = ...

    // do whatever you need to do, then return

    return processedResponse
  }
  return axios.get('/example.com')
    .then(processResponse)
}

// then, you can use `getUsersFrom3rdParty` as a promise
exports.getUsers = (req, res, next) => {
  const handleResponse = (data) => {
    res.json({ data }) // or whatever you need to do
  }
  const handleError = (err) => {
    res.json({ error: 'Something went wrong!' }) // or whatever you need to do
  }

  getUsersFrom3rdParty(...)
    .then(handleResponse)
    .catch(handleError)
}
```

This way, you're waiting for your API call to finish before you render something and/or return a response.

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing options variable when you are calling getUsersFrom3rdParty function

```
var data = getUsersFrom3rdParty(options);
```

You have to pass options to make it work and I suggest to use request module .It works better than https module.

Here is your code using request

```
const request = require("request");

function getUsersFrom3rdParty(options) {
  request(options, (error, response, body) => {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
      //Returned data
      console.log(JSON.parse(body));
    }
  });
}

exports.getUsers = (req, res, next) => {
  var data = getUsersFrom3rdParty(options);
};
```